# How to read zip file header manually

Tags: zip, unzip

I have a file in which i have very important java project source code that got lost.
It is an elf-file. When i open it with and editor most of it is unreadable but the complete java project seems to be embedded as a uncompressed zip folder inside the file with folderstructure and everything (dont ask me why. I only try to get the information back i am not responsible).

The relevant information pieces in the elf-file look like the following:

```
PK
  Üi‰L§½kQ   Q   9   file/path/i/cant/show/contenttext
content
content
```

Because i dont know where the zip folder starts and where it ends and because everything is uncompressed my idea was to write a small script to scrape the from the elf-file and create the complete javaproject from that.

For that i want the file name length from the header so its easy to know where filename ends end filecontent starts.

This`PK Üi‰L§½kQ   Q   9`    seems to be the file header of the zipfile. I converted it to hex and it looks like this: `504B03040A2020082020DC69894CA71E BD6B512020205120202039202020`
I tried to format that with the info from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)#Local_file_header):

```
504B0304 //sig (this showed me i did something right)
0A20 // version
2008 // generalpurpose flag
2020 // compression method
DC69 // File last modification time 
894C // File last modification date 
A71EBD6B //CRC-32 of uncompressed data 
51202020 //Compressed size (or 0xffffffff for ZIP64) 
51202020 //Uncompressed size (or 0xffffffff for ZIP64) 
3920  //File name length (n) 
2020 //Extra field length (m)
```

And Endian switch:

```
04034B50 //sig
200A // version
0820 // generalpurpose flag
2020 // compression method
69DC // File last modification time 
4C89 // File last modification date 
6BBD1EA7 //CRC-32 of uncompressed data 
20202051 //Compressed size (or 0xffffffff for ZIP64) 
20202051 //Uncompressed size (or 0xffffffff for ZIP64) 
2039  //File name length (n) 
2020 //Extra field length (m)
```

But something seems wrong. The length of the file header is right (30 bytes plus filename) and the numbers seem to have information at the right point but `2020` should be `0000` for compression. To me it seems the conversion to hex is only half right.
What do i have to change to get the right numbers?

Comment: This might be obvious, but have you tried opening it with the ZIP tool of your choice? ZIP files are weird, because they don't necessarily need to have their header at the beginning of the files (due to the way the file format is constructed). This makes them very good at being appended/embedded in other file formats (such as ELF here) and still be open-able as "normal" ZIP file. So something like `unzip -t yourfile` could work. If that doesn't work then the `-F` or `-FF` flags of Info-ZIP (which comes with many Linux distributions, so you might already have it) might help recovering the ZIP.

Comment: yes i tried that (and tried it again right now to make sure). To me it seems that the zip files are embedded inside the .text section of the elf file and its hard to see where it starts and where it ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error.
The problem of the weird 2020 instead of 0000 was my mistake. I opened the file in notepadd++ copied interesting sections into a new file and converted them there into hex. I think the copying changed the data. When i open the file directly in a hexeditor the zipefile header is all right.